# __result not declared in this scope

Tags: rcpp

Hi I am getting an error "__result was not declared in this scope". There is no variable "result" any more. "outResult" was named "result" before. But renamed.

I did cut down the code. It makes no sense but is simple now and I get the error.

Are there any temporary files which I could delete?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Rf_warning
// [[Rcpp::export]]

// Function findPIPs_cpp
NumericVector findPIPs_cpp(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {

  IntegerVector PIPs(x.size());
  IntegerVector outResult(x.size());  
  NumericVector PIPLine(x.size()); // Interpolated Values


  outResult[0] = 0;
  outResult[1] = y.size()-1;

     int i = 0;
     int n = 1;

    // sort the existing PIPs
    PIPs = outResult[outResult > 0];
    std::sort(PIPs.begin(), PIPs.end());

    // first point of the interpolated line
    PIPLine[0] = y[PIPs[0]];


    PIPLine[n] = margin *  (x[PIPs[i]]-x[PIPs[i+1]]) + y[PIPs[i]];



  return PIPLine;


}
```

Comment: If you check the documentation in the Rcpp-Attributes vignette, it becomes clear that you simply use `sourceCpp()` the wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tooke me some time to figure it out. 
It is the line between

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
```

and the function name which is the problem. After removing the comment it runs

```
// Function findPIPs_cpp
```

So for others - DO NOT COMMENT there. 
Still would be fine to know why. ;)

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: As for why -- the Rcpp attributes parser expects the function definition to lie immediately following the comment; it's not 'smart' enough to walk through other comments following after.